# How to change the color of a canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, background-color

I know how to do this very easily in CSS but I wanted to know how you would make the default white canvas black using Javascript. I got the total number of circles that I want on top of the background but every attempt I make to change background color gets rid of my circles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Loops Homework</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,0,0,0.8)";


fillCircle(200,200,i*2);

fillCircle(150,200,i*2);

fillCircle(100,200,i*2);

fillCircle(0,200,i*2);

fillCircle(50,200,i*2);

fillCircle(250,200,i*2);

fillCircle(300,200,i*2);

fillCircle(350,200,i*2);

fillCircle(400,200,i*2);

fillCircle(450,200,i*2);
}


var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = 100;


function fillCircle(x, y, radius) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: `java != javascript`, and in fact the languages are **very** different. I'v e changed your [tag:java] tag to [tag:javascript] but in the future, you'll want to be careful with your question tags so that your question attracts the correct experts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you start drawing circles, fill the entire canvas with black using `fillRect`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// fill the entire canvas with black before drawing the circles
ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

...
```

Comment: @GameAlchemist, this is a question from a someone new to canvas and it has a simple answer. Why the downvote?

Comment: You could probably just use css for the element in this case (`background-color:black`). Besides from that I cannot see any error with the answer so it shouldn't have been downvoted IMHO.

Comment: hi, my png background is transparent after rotating the png corner of my image is black how to transparent ??